# Get id Corrdinate javascript leaflet

Tags: leaflet

How can I get the ID I gave to a polygon by clicking?

```
var geojson = {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [{
                    "postalAreaId": item.PostalAreaId,
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "Coors Field",
                        "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
                        "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
                    },
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Polygon",
                        "coordinates": []
                    }
                }]
            };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OnEachFeature option](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) when you draw your features on the map... A possible solution would be:

```js
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "postalAreaId": 1,
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Coors Field",
                "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
                "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-105.00341892242432, 39.75383843460583],
            }
        },
        {
            "postalAreaId": 2,
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Coors Field",
                "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
                "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates":     [-105.0008225440979, 39.751891803969535],
            }
        }]
};
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.74739, -105], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
        alert(feature.postalAreaId)
    })
}

L.geoJSON(geojson, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

#map {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

In this case, I'm using `click` but you could also use `mousein` and `mouseout`. Basically, inside the `onEachFeature` function you're adding a listener that will check events that happen on each feature of the map.

Comment: Thanks, it was great
How can I check the user position without clicking whether it is in a polygon or not

Comment: I want to get the user status from the browser and then postalareaid it https://usaupload.com/4Xij/2021-09-25_17-33-49.jpg